# HTML5 Pac-Man game

Tags: javascript, game, css, html5

I'm testing my game using Firefox, and it's slow whenever it's in fullscreen. If I resize the browser to take up half the screen, it'll scale the image down and run fine. Game also runs fine in Chrome in full screen. I'm using a laptop with an i7 4000HD series CPU..

The window size shouldn't make a difference, as I have set the canvas size to have a size of 672 by 312 pixels, and then I stretch the width to 100% and height to auto in CSS.

```
<canvas id="background" width="672" height="312">
</canvas>
<canvas id="ground" width="672" height="312">
</canvas>
<canvas id="dirt" width="672" height="312">
</canvas>
<canvas id="actors" width="672" height="312" tabindex="1">
</canvas>
<canvas id="outermaze" width="672" height="312">
</canvas>
<canvas id="scorelayer" width="672" height="312">
</canvas>
<canvas id="foreground" width="672" height="312">
</canvas>

canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin:auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: -4;
}
```

The game can be played at [www.thestevester.com/pacmental/index.html](http://www.thestevester.com/pacmental/index.html)

Is the way I'm stretching the canvas to fullscreen causing performance issues?

What's even goofier is that when I set the resolution of Windows from 1440p to 1080p, it runs fine...

Comment: I showed the relevant code for the question I asked...

Comment: Game is great. :)) What's the programming language underneath? C++ ?

Comment: thanks!  it's javascript...  based on the Shaun Williams version...

Comment: Crazy stuff. It runs absolutely fast and smoothly. Never expected this done in a high level, interpreted language. Anyway: Congrats.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you!  It's a testament to both MODERN PROCESSING and Shaun Williams's excellence in programming!  I didn't know you could make a web game with C++....